Which loss function should be used if sum(y_true)=1?
My yTrue are basically like [.2,.8] but never [1,0] or [0,1]
sum(yTrue)=1 always
I tried CategoricalCrossentropy But a TypeError occured-

TypeError: Expected float32, but got <keras.src.losses.losses.CategoricalCrossentropy object at 0x7752c1300580> of type 'CategoricalCrossentropy'.


Categorical cross entropy is for classification. The loss function is the negative of the sum of y_i*log(f(y_i)) where f(y_i) is your model's probability prediction. It looks like you have an array of probabilities for y=0 and y=1. You need to choose one of these, typically y=1, as your target variable and convert to probabilities to labels:
y[y>=0.5]=1
y[y<0.5]=0

or
y = (y >= 0.5).astype(int)


That would work but That isn't the goal both float in yTrue represent how good that decision would be,Any other solution ?

Can you provide me with more details about what you are trying to do?

The yTrue here is the ratio of how high and low (in %) did price of a stock went from current price
And I'm trying to predict that ratio

So to clarify, you want to predict low/current_price and high/current_price? In this case, you have a multi-output regression, and cross-entropy is not a suitable loss function. Instead, you'll want to use mean squared error. Also, if they always sum to 1 then you only need to predict one of them and can obtain the other by 1-prediction.
